# Javascript - Looping over an array of objects, only last object show

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

i spent a bit trying to make title that explained the issued but i fear it fell a bit short of the issue i am having.

in short, i am using a for loop to iterate over this array of objects.

```
var people = [
  {
      name: "John Doe",
      age: 33,
      gender: "male",
      loc: "Springfield"
   },
   {
      name: "Jane Doe",
      age: 32,
      gender: "female",
      loc: "Springfield"
   }
];
```

The for loop is run through a function passing two arguments, an element id and the array, like this.

```
var list = {
  html: function (el, array) {
    var container = document.getElementById(el), html;    
    for( var i=0;i<array.length;i++ ) {
      html  = '<div class="item">';
      html +=   '<h1>'+array[i].name+'</h1>';
      html +=   '<p>Age: '+array[i].age+'</p>';
      html +=   '<p>Sex: '+array[i].gender+'</p>';
      html +=   '<p>Location: '+array[i].loc+'</p>';
      html += '</div>';     
      console.log( array[i].name+', '+array[i].age+', '+array[i].gender+', '+array[i].loc );  
    } 
    container.innerHTML = html; 
  } 
}
list.html('list', people);
```

**The problem:** The loop returns only the last object in the array. I am unsure why this is happening or how to solve it. Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Here is a link to a: [relevant demo](http://codepen.io/fmrogers/pen/jqBvoQ)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Init `html` var with empty string and add `+` in the beginning of `for` loop:

```
var container = document.getElementById(el), html = "";   
for( var i=0;i<array.length;i++ ) {
    html  += '<div class="item">';  // add plus here
```

Comment: Also make sure you do `html = ''` at the beginning.

Comment: @u_mulder, Thank you kind sir. I do hate it when the solution stares me in the face. Hva a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

The first instruction inside the foor loop is an assignment

```
html  = '<div class="item">'
```

so on every iteration the whole content of "html" gets replaced. 
You should use

```
html += '<div class="item">';
```

Comment: thank you. It never occurred to me that i was replacing the value of my variable. Such a simple mistake, but so easy to fix. Have a nice day.